# Altering hypotheses of Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This came up in an earlier question I was working on here. I won't bore you with the statement of LDCT . . .

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

My question is, can we interchange the limit and integral if $|f_n(x)| \le g(x)$ for all $x$ and for all $n \ge M$? i.e. the function $g$ dominates $f_n$ for sufficently large $n$?

Earlier I was told this was OK, and I have been trying to prove it, but the proofs of LDCT rely heavily on Fatou (in particular the reverse Fatou Lemma), and there you need an inequality for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Certainly. Just replace the sequence $f_n$ with $g_n = f_{n+M}$.

Comment: lol i should've seen that . . . i'll quickly accept if you put it as an answer

Comment: The only problem is your sequence may consist of undefined objects in the first $M-1$ slots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly. Just replace the sequence $f_n$ with $g_n = f_{n+M}$.

In general when working with the limit of a sequence, you can remove any finite number of terms without affecting the result.